# SOLR Collection memory consumed

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs

I need to know how much memory my SOLR collection is consuming for indexing and storing data but couldn't find any credible source for that. I've used hdfs dfs -du on the paths hdfs://nameservice1/solr1/my_collection/core_node1/data but it gives two different data sizes: 
143.3 M  429.8 M  hdfs://nameservice1/solr1/my_collection/core_node1/data 
but I don't if this is correct path to look or which size is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Depending, if you are looking for memory (RAM) size used by solr or storage (disk) size, you could take a look on the solr admin pannel.

Just access the admin pannel by using an web browser to your solr host, like
http://host:port/app, like http://mysolrhost:8080/solr.

On the dashboard you will find the memory useage and on the "core admin" page you will find the size on disk.

Comment: Hi @TheBndr, Just checked the core-admin page and selected my shard but there is nothing like size on disk on this page. I can see two things Core and Index and there is information like dataDir, directory and etc. I checked size on disk on dataDir, please confirm if this is the space consumed by my collection.